# Error al ejecutar "bower install" error "ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy 1.5.3"

Tags: git, bower

[image: esta es la consola en donde se ve el error]
No sé porque trata de instalar la libreria "canvg#1.5.3" si en el bower.json no está referenciada esta librería, por favor su ayuda, gracias.

### Este es mi bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "genesys",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.6",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.6",
    "angular-aria": "^1.6.4",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "angular-chart.js": "1.1.1",
    "angular-cookies": "1.6.9",
    "angularjs-crypto": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-material-data-table": "^0.10.10",
    "angular-material-icons": "^0.7.1",
    "angular-material-sidenav": "^0.0.14",
    "angular-messages": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-resource": "^1.6.4",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.6.9",
    "angular-ui-notification": "^0.3.6",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.4.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "fontawesome#^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.2.2",
    "ng-loaders": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-table": "~0.8.3",
    "please-wait": "^0.0.5",
    "smDateTimeRangePicker": "^2.0.10",
    "ng-scrollbars": "^0.0.11",
    "angular-endless-scroll": "^0.1.0",
    "alasql": "0.2.6",
    "ngstorage": "^0.3.11",
    "ng-ip-address": "^1.1.11",
    "angular-perfect-scrollbar-working": "^0.1.0",
    "angular-notification-icons": "^0.4.4",
    "angular-ui-grid": "4.1.0",
    "google-chart": "1.1.2",
    "angular-google-chart": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "mdPickers": "^0.7.5",
    "md-pickers": "^1.1.0",
    "material-scrolltop": "^0.6.4",
    "svg-morpheus": "^0.3.2",
    "angular-mousewheel": "^1.0.5",
    "angular-breadcrumb": "^0.5.0",
    "angular-material-expansion-panel": "^0.7.2",
    "xmdwizard": "xmdWizard#*",
    "numbro": "^1.11.1",
    "hot-formula-parser": "^2.3.1",
    "angular-loading-bar": "^0.9.0",
    "angular-collapsible-block-directive": "ng-collapsible-block#^0.0.2",
    "angular-drag-and-drop-lists": "^2.1.0",
    "aos": "^2.2.0",
    "angular-cron-gen": "^0.0.26",
    "angular-cron-jobs": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-grid-tree": "^0.4.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "angular-fixed-table-header": "^0.2.1",
    "md-steppers": "^0.3.4",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "0.4.8",
    "angular-google-analytics": "^1.1.9",
    "angular-owl-carousel2": "*",
    "angular-daterangepicker": "^0.2.2",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.36",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.4",
    "angular-ui-select": "^0.19.8",
    "SpinKit": "spinkit#^1.2.5",
    "handsontable": "0.34.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-multiselect": "https://github.com/bentorfs/angular-bootstrap-multiselect.git#^1.1.11"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "genesysApp",
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.6.6",
    "angular-cookies": "1.6.9",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.4.2",
    "jquery": ">=1.2.2",
    "js-xlsx": "^0.9.5",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    },
    "font-awesome": {
      "main": [
        "less/font-awesome.less",
        "css/font-awesome.css"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Intenta ejecutar este comando

bower install https://github.com/canvg/canvg.git#v1.5.3 -S